# Jenkins - how to configure restricted but useful user account

Tags: security, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, user-accounts

In Jenkins - how to configure restricted but useful user account that can to: view, cancel and replay runs for selected jobs only?

Answer (score 0):

(Tested on Jenkins 2.235)

1. Configure global security (for all projects/jobs):

```
Login as admin.
Manage Jenkins.
Configure Global Security.
Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy.
Add user or group.
User or group name.
<enter username>
Check the following checkboxes:
Overall.Read
Agent.Build, 
Job.Build, Job.Cancel, 
Run.Delete, Run.Replay, Run.Update
Save
```

2. Configure local security (for selected project(s)/job(s)):

```
Jenkins->All
<choose existing pipeline>
<select dropdown on the pipeline name>
Configure
Enable project-based security <checkbox>
Add user or group
User or group name
<enter username>
Check the following checkboxes:
Job.Build, Job.Cancel, Job.Read,
Run.Delete, Run.Replay, Run.Update, 
Save
Logout
```

3. Testing

```
Login as <username>
you should see only one pipeline
Test if Build Now works (this action is by default disabled)
Switch to Blue Ocean view
Message should say: "Started by user <username>"
Click the Stop button on the latest run
Status should change to "aborted"
Click on the Rerun button
<refresh>
Message should change to "Replayed #<run ID>"
```

Note that [Github OAuth Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/github-oauth/) nicely integrates with Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy, only in this case instead of Jenkins internal user names one has to use existing Github's user names e.g. when authorizing Github project collaborators to run Jenkins builds.

Answer (score 0):

A much more scalable alternative would be to use [Role-based Authorization Strategy](https://plugins.jenkins.io/role-strategy/) Jenkins plugin. However, do not try this at home, as it seems to require an LDAP server:

1. Install the plugin
2. Enable the plugin:
   Manage Jenkins -> Configure Global Security -> Authorization: Role-Based Strategy  -> Save
3. Create new role, e.g. pipeline-user:
   Manage Jenkins -> Uncategorized: Manage and Assign Roles -> Manage Roles -> Global roles -> Role to add -> pipeline-user -> Add -> Add these roles (using checkboxes): Overall.Read, Job.Build, Job.Cancel, Job.Read, Run.Delete, Run.Replay, Run.Update -> Save
4. Assign users the newly created role
   Manage Jenkins -> Uncategorized: Manage and Assign Roles -> Assign Roles -> Global roles -> User to add ->  -> Add -> pipeline-user  -> User to add ->  -> Add -> pipeline-user  -> Save

After attempted login as user1, Jenkins does not correctly recognize user1 permissions.